# Elasticsearch Hightlight with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

I'm currently working on a frontend for Elasticsearch with AngularJS. Search query is working quite well, expect from hightlighting.

In my service.js I have put my search query which looks like:

```
client.search({
            "index": "index_name",
            "type": "index_type",
            "body": {
                "size": 10,
                "from": offset,
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": query
                    }
                },
                "highlight" : {
                    "fields" : {
                        "*" : {}
                    }
                }
            }
}).then(function(result) {...}
```

I checked the json on my chrome but there is no field highlight (as it should be)

In Kibana I tested highlighting with this query:

```
GET /_search {
    "query" : {
        "match": { "message": "test" }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "*" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the result + hightlighting

Any suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually quite easy:

```
     client.search({
        index: CALACA_CONFIGS.index_name,
        type: CALACA_CONFIGS.type,
        body: {
            size: CALACA_CONFIGS.size,
            from: offset,
            query: {
                query_string: {
                    query: query
                }
            },
            highlight : {
            require_field_match: false,  <-- added this line
                fields : {
                    "*" : {fragment_size: 10, number_of_fragments: 0}
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function(result) { .. }
```